# What does e a large triangle with a yellow exclamation mark on my iPad Launch Image mean?

Tags: xcode, ipad

I am converting my iPhone app to a universal app and just added the launch image for the iPad. The image works fine, but in xCode there is a large triangle with an exclamation mark in it. What does this mean? I thought it might because the file size was too large? I reduced it from a meg to 168k and the triangle is still there.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It most likely means that the image dimensions are wrong. They should be 768 x 1004 (W x H) for an iPad launch image in portrait. For landscape it should be 1024 x 748 (W x H).

You should also be able to hover over the yellow triangle to see the same error.

Apple's guidelines for launch image size are here: [iOS HIG, Image Sizes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Comment: Guess before I posted my question I did not wait long enough in the hover. You are correct it is complaining about the dimensions. It is a landscape image and in Fireworks it says it is 1024x748. Not sure what more I can do. It works fine. Should I just ignore it?

Comment: It does take a while for the error to come up. Look in your project directory, and see how large `startup-Portrait~ipad.png` is. It may be that you need to delete that, and add the image again in the project info panel in Xcode.

Comment: get info on the image also says it's 1024x748. While I got you, do have any idea what a reasonable size for an iPad launch image? The one I made's original size was over a meg, and now it's 168k. It looks ok, but not as good as the larger one.

Comment: Try cleaning the project, and cleaning the build folder (hold option when you have the product menu open). I don't think that there is a restriction on file size, try the larger size image and see if the app launches any slower. I suspect ~ 1000k is okay.

Comment: I deleted it from xCode all together, added the file back in to resources and dragged it back to the landscape position in the summary view of the target. Still complaining.

Comment: I'd just ignore it then. If the error you see when you hover is definitely wrong size, and you know it's the right size, it's not worth worrying about that much.

Comment: That's what I was just thinking. Thank you so much for you help.